# Save and show an image in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

i want to know how can i do to save and show an image in the image view.

My app have 2 buttons and depending on wich button was pressed the image view get an image. What i want to do is to save that image and when i open the app again the choosen image is still there.

The only way i know to save something is shared preferences but in this case it doesnt work.

Someone can help my? Thank

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView imagen;
Button boton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen);
    boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton);

    SharedPreferences preferences= getSharedPreferences("Preferencias", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String imagen= preferences.getString("Imagen", null);
}

public void boton1(View view){

    imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen1);

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("Imagen", imagen.getResources().toString());
    editor.apply();
}

public void boton2(View view){

    imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen2);

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("Imagen", imagen.getResources().toString());
    editor.apply();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could save the URI in String format of the drawable in your shared preference. Like this (rename yourImageName by the drawable name) :

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+context.getPackageName()+"/drawable/yourImageName");
String uri_toString = imageUri.toString();  

SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("imageUri", uri_toString);
editor.apply();
```

In your MainActivity, in `onResume` set the image source of your ImageView like this :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Preferencias", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String imageUri = preferences.getString("imageUri",null);

if (imageUri != null) {
   Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageUri);
   yourImageView.setImageURI(uri);
}
```

Comment: Hi, it works except for  if (imageUri != null){
           imagen.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }